# Authentication in mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to connect to a mongodb database using authentication. My code for doing so is the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('ip', port)
client.prod_db.authenticate('username', 'pass',  source='source_database')
```

However I am receiving the following error in the authentication line:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

Am I doing the whole authentication thing wrongly?

**EDIT:** Also tried to use the following schema:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@ip:port/')
```

And I received the same mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons that may cause the `Authentication` to fail.

- First check that you allow your ip for bindip. Use `0.0.0.0` to allow all clients to access the MongoServer.
- Pass **mechanism** also in the `authenticate()` as an argument.

Something like this works for me :

```
client = MongoClient('127.0.0.1', 27017)
client.admin.authenticate('username', 'pass', mechanism = 'SCRAM-SHA-1', source='source_database')
db_name = client[db]
col_name = col_name
col = db_name[col_name]
```

Comment: But where exactly I am adding the pass?

Comment: `mechanism = 'SCRAM-SHA-1'`

Comment: Are you able to authenticate in mongo shell ?

Comment: I am able to authenticate in robomongo. Didnt tried in the shell.

Comment: What is the python and mongo version ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139746/discussion-between-satish-garg-and-konstantin).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you have to percent-escape your username and password if it has characters that need to be escaped, but the method in Satish's answer should actually allow you to not worry about that. However, if you'd like to try the percent-escaping method, as outlined in the [PyMongo 3.5.1 docs](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html), you might do that as follows (python 3):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib.parse

username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('user') # username = 'user'

password = urllib.parse.quote_plus('pass/word') # password = 'pass%2Fword'

MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@127.0.0.1' % (username, password))
```

This will default to authenticating in the 'test' database. To authenticate in a specific database, do the following instead

```
MongoClient('mongodb://user:password@example.com/[YOUR DB]?[AUTH MECHANISM]')
```

For Python 2 you use "urllib.quote_plus()" to percent escape.